# Is this a lucky person or an unlucky person?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

Suppose a person is such that when he is presented a number of choices out of which one is 'correct' and the others give nothing, most of the time he lands on the that choice.

Suppose he plays a game in which he has to choose one card out of a million cards. Suppose the 937th card is the 'correct one' and has a 'prize'.

Now, if the game was 'whoever gets the 'correct' card wins 100000$', then that person will be considered very lucky because out of all the million cards, he landed on 937.

But if the game was 'whoever gets the 'correct' card gets burned alive', then the same person will be the unluckiest person ever because out of all the choices, the one that he landed on was 937.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A question like this explores the definition of "lucky."

One definition of lucky is buried in statistics.  One could define lucky based on the P-value of the events that occur around them.  P-values look at the probability of a more extreme event occurring.  By this definition of lucky, he would still remain "lucky."

However, when exploring "lucky" in a non-mathematical sense, we often associate the desirability of the results with how lucky or unlucky we are.  Having a freak event destroy one's life is typically not considered lucky.

Consider Cassandra.  She could pick the correct card, for she can see the future.  Cassandra can always predict the future perfectly.  It was a gift from Apollo before their marriage day.  After she jilted him, he adjusted the gift.  She can still predict the future perfectly, but now nobody will believe her.  She must go around knowing every catastrophe that will ever happen, but be completely impotent to do anything about it?

Is she lucky?

Answer (score 1):

The Internet Encyclopedia of Philosophy contains an entry on this topic under [General Features of Luck](http://www.iep.utm.edu/luck/#SH1c). Perhaps there you can find a good answer there.

After reading some of it, I would say that the answer to the question is that it depends on how formally we define "lucky".

> Goodness and badness. Luck can be good or bad. This is clearly true of relational luck. For instance, we say things such as “Dylan was lucky to survive the car accident” or “Dylan was unlucky to die in the car accident” to mean, respectively, that it is good luck that he survived and bad luck that he died. Moreover, one and the same event can be both good and bad luck for an agent, which plausibly has to do with the fact that two or more interests of the agent are at stake—Ballantyne (2012). For example, losing one’s keys and having to spend the night outdoors is bad luck if one gets a cold as a consequence, but it is also good luck if one thereby avoids an explosion in one’s apartment.
>
> By contrast, attributions of non-relational luck not so clearly convey good or bad luck—for example, “The discovery of Pluto was a matter of luck.” This is plausibly due to the fact that such attributions do not denote any relationship between a lucky event and an agent or group of agents. To put it differently, if we interpret that sort of attributions as conveying good or bad luck, it is probably because we read them as denoting such relationship. At any rate, accounting for why luck is good or bad is a desideratum at least for analyses of relational luck.
>
> Finally, although the term “lucky” is ordinarily associated with good luck, in the philosophical literature, it is used to denote events that instantiate good luck as well as events that instantiate bad luck. This is done mainly for the sake of simplicity.

So, from this point of view, I would say the person choosing the card that wins a prize is lucky, and the one the choose the card that implies a punishment is unlucky.

However, the same article also contains a section about [probabilistic accounts](http://www.iep.utm.edu/luck/#H3) in which luck can be defined in more objective ways.

For example, if lucky was defined a little more objectively as:

> A significant event E is lucky for an agent S at time t if only if, prior to the occurrence of E at t, there was low probability that E would occur at t.

Then in both cases in the OP I would say the agent was lucky, since under this definition all that matters is the occurrence of the unprovable event, more than the effects of the occurrence of such event on the agent.